# I can't display 4 Card in middle of page with Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CardNote extends StatelessWidget {
  const CardNote({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: const [
              Card(
                elevation: 3,
                color: Colors.amber,
                child: SizedBox(
                  width: 200,
                  height: 200,
                  child: Center(
                      child: Text(
                    'Card 1',
                  )),
                ),
              ),
              Card(
                elevation: 3,
                color: Colors.amber,
                child: SizedBox(
                  width: 200,
                  height: 200,
                  child: Center(
                      child: Text(
                    'Card 2',
                  )),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

When I add this widget to the page where I want to show the cards, I can show 2 widgets in a single line. Then when I call the same widget again, I get the following error.

**RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox object was given an infinite size during layout.This probably means that it is a render object that tries to be as big as possible, but it was put inside another render object that allows its children to pick their own size.**

```
return Scaffold(
  body: Container(
    child: Row(
      children: const [
        CardNote(),
        SizedBox(
          height: 50,
        ),
        CardNote()
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

This is how I add the cards to the page I want to show.

[image]

This is how I want to show 4 cards in the middle of the page

[image]

This is how it looks on my page. It shows at the top of the page, not in the middle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your `CardNote` widget with `Expanded` widget. And use a top level scrollable widget. Also you dont need to us multiple scaffold

```dart
home: Scaffold(
  body: Center(
    child: Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: const [
        CardNote(),
        SizedBox(
          height: 50,
        ),
        CardNote(),
      ],
    ),
  ),
),
```

While the card is fixed width, you can provide it

```dart
class CardNote extends StatelessWidget {
  const CardNote({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Container(
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: const [
            Card(
              elevation: 3,
              color: Colors.amber,
              child: SizedBox(
                width: 200,
                height: 200,
                child: Center(
                    child: Text(
                  'Card 1',
                )),
              ),
            ),
            Card(
              elevation: 3,
              color: Colors.amber,
              child: SizedBox(
                width: 200,
                height: 200,
                child: Center(
                    child: Text(
                  'Card 2',
                )),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, my problem is solved, but the 4 cards appear at the top of the page, not in the middle. To fix this I replaced Row with Column and wrapped it with center. But it didn't work

Comment: Can you include an image that you are trying to archive

Comment: I think I've got what you want, try update answer

Comment: I added how the design should be.

Comment: Try update one  snippet

Comment: Glad to help, you can find more about [ui/layout](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add a row which has alignment of spaceEven inside another row. When you added the first set of cards it got aligned evenly. On second set you have 2 set of rows inside a row each one has alignment of spaceEven..

Depending on the layout if you wish to show these cards one below the other set then use a Column widget

```dart
return Scaffold(
  body: Container(
    child: Column(//here
      children: const [
        CardNote(),
        SizedBox(
          height: 50,
        ),
        CardNote()
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```